# Ajax gets only success response in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

My ajax code always receives a success response even in case of error.
I'm using Laravel 8.2.

Here is JavaScript

```
    $(".deleteRecord").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
    if(confirm('Do you want to delete?')){
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "operDel/"+id,
                type: 'post',
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    "id": id,
                    "method": 'post',
                    "_token": token,
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function() {
                    alert('Record is deleted'); // I getting only this alert
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('You can not delete this record');
                }
            });
    }
});
```

Here is Route

```
Route::post('operDel/{id}', '\App\Http\Controllers\OperationController@destroy')->name('operDel')->middleware('auth');
```

Here is Contoller

```
    public function destroy($id)
{

    $user = User::find($id);
    if($user->type !== 0) {
            $user->delete();
            return response()->json([
                'success'=>"Record deleted."
            ]);
    }
    else{
        return response()->json([
            'error' => "You can not delete this"
        ]);
    }
}
```

The controller is running without error, it deleted record from DB when $user-> type! == 0.
But I'm getting only the alert within the success function.
How can I display response message to alert?

Comment: Your issue is you are not using the framework as you should, you should be using [Gates](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#gates) to authorize the request and also use [Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation) to do that... The most important thing is that you read the entire documentation, so you can know what does the framework offers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send error response codes in order for AJAX to consider a response to have failed, for example:

```
public function destroy($id)
{

    $user = User::find($id);
    if($user->type !== 0) {
            $user->delete();
            return response()->json([
                'success'=>"Record deleted."
            ]);
    }
    else{
        return response()->json([
            'error' => "You can not delete this"
        ], 400); // 400 means bad request
    }
}
```

Sending a response code that's 400+ will make AJAX understand that there was an error.

Comment: `400` or `401` (unauthorized) or `403` (forbidden)